# Сложить числа через рекурсию

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```js
function sum(n,m) {
  if (n != 1 && m != 1) {
    return (sum(n - 1, m) + 1) + (sum(n, m - 1) + 1);
  } else {
    return n + m;
  }
}

console.log(sum(2,2)); // 8 результат не тот, что ожидался
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: Опечатка. `=!` и `!=` это совсем совсем разные вещи

Comment: Точно! ответ теперь 8, опять не тот что нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sum(n,m) {
  if(n==0) return m;
  if(m==0) return n;
    k=sum(n - 1, m);

    return ++k;
}
```

Вот так операция сложения вообще не будет вызываться.

Comment: `++k` - это не операция сложения что ли?

Comment: Нет, это инкремент, он выполняется быстрее, есть машинный код для этого.

Comment: для операции `a = a + b` тоже потребуется всего одна инструкция процессора (если a и b помещены в регистры, либо если b - некая константа). Ну и, например, у arm-процессоров нет инструкции инкремента, когда-то много писал на ассемблере для arm... Зы. говоря про JS вообще неуместно упоминать машинный код, имхо :)

Comment: Ну все-таки... Предположим, что бинарный + не определен. Тогда его можно определить так.

Comment: т.е. бинарное сложение не определено, а вычитание - есть (`n - 1`)? Это ведь одно и то же, или отрицательных чисел тоже не существует? А вообще топик очень странный, конечно...

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka если я не ошибаюсь то такой инкремент не используется, потому-что не изменяет флаг переноса.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, а за счет чего два аргумента складываются? 0_o, я был бы **очень признателен** если бы вы объяснили пошагово как выполняется Ваша функция

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович
n+0=0
n+m=(n-1)+m+1

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, спасибо, ничего не понял, видимо вернусь к этому 
 объяснению позже

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович рекурсивно доходим до случая, когда одно из чисел равно 0, тогда сумма равна другому числу.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka , теперь внимательней присмотрелся к условию и всё   увидел, хороший способ! Поставлю вам принятый ответ!А Вы бы не могли еще объяснить, что хотел сказать **Grundy** под моим ответом пожалуйта, он хотел решить функцию рекурсией, **без** её базиса?

Comment: Чтобы определить сложение, нам нужно использовать другие операции, определенные ранее. Максимум сложение с 1. Если имеем  сложение с 1, вычитание единицы, рекурсивно определим сложение любых чисел.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Собственно решить вашим способом

Answer (score 1):

Потому что жестко слишком - получается, что на каждой итерации у Вас удваивается результат (ко всему прочему).

```js
function sum(n,m) {
    if (n > 1) {
        return (sum(n - 1, m) + 1);
    } else if(m > 1) {
        return (sum(n, m - 1) + 1);
    } else {
        return n + m;
    }
}

console.log(sum(2,2)); //2 результат не тот, что ожидался
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sum(n, m) {
  if (n != 1 && m != 1) {
    return (sum(n - 1, m) + 1); /*вместо return (sum(n - 1, m) + 1) + (sum(n, m - 1) + 1); получается я складывал результат функции  с результатом функции, мда уж =)*/
  } else {
    return n + m;
  }
}

console.log(sum(2, 2)); /* Ответ 4 */
```

Comment: плохое решение из-за наличия `return n + m;`. Раз есть эта строка, то остальные строки можно выкинуть. суть ведь задачи, как раз уйти от стандартного оператора `+`. Оставив лишь `+1` и `-1`